# UWP - Saving Files. IOException: The process cannot access the file 'file path' because it is being used by another process

Tags: file, uwp, picker

I wanted to save a file in UWP. My code snippet is below.
This works sometimes. But fails sometimes. Not sure why?
This typically happens if the file to be saved is bigger or there are multiple files to be saved.

```
private async void Download_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear previous returned file name, if it exists, between iterations of this scenario
        //          TextBlock1.Text = "";

        FileSavePicker savePicker = new FileSavePicker();
        savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
        // Dropdown of file types the user can save the file as
        savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("CSV Format", new List<string>() { ".csv" });
        // Default file name if the user does not type one in or select a file to replace
        savePicker.SuggestedFileName = "DataBaseFile1";
        StorageFile file = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();

        using (var stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        {
            stream.SetLength(0);
            var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Content");
            await stream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            await stream.FlushAsync();
        }


        if (file != null)
        {
            // Prevent updates to the remote version of the file until we finish making changes and call CompleteUpdatesAsync.
            CachedFileManager.DeferUpdates(file);
            // write to file
            //   await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, "Example file contents.");

            using (var stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, AllRecordsTitle_TBlock.Text);
                await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, "\n");
                await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, "\n");
                await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, IDTitle_TBlock.Text);
                await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, "\n");
                await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, ID_TBlock.Text);
                await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, "\n");
                await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, FirstNameTitle_TBlock.Text);
                await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, "\n");
                await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, FirstName_TBlock.Text);
                await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, "\n");
                await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, LastNameTitle_TBlock.Text);
                await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, "\n");
                await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, LastName_TBlock.Text);
                await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, "\n");
                await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, TelNo1Title_TBlock.Text);
                await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, "\n");
                await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, TelNo1_TBlock.Text);
                await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, "\n");
                await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, TelNo2Title_TBlock.Text);
                await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, "\n");
                await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, TelNo2_TBlock.Text);
                await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, "\n");
                await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, EmailTitle_TBlock.Text);
                await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, "\n");
                await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, Email_TBlock.Text);
                await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, "\n");
                await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, "\n");
                await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, AddressTitle_TBlock.Text);
                await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, "\n");
                await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, Address_TBlock.Text);
                await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, "\n");
                await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, DetailsTitle_TBlock.Text);
                await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, "\n");
                await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, Details_TBlock.Text);
                await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, "\n");


            }
            // Let Windows know that we're finished changing the file so the other app can update the remote version of the file.
            // Completing updates may require Windows to ask for user input.
            FileUpdateStatus status = await CachedFileManager.CompleteUpdatesAsync(file);
            if (status == FileUpdateStatus.Complete)
            {
                // TextBlock1.Text = "File " + file.Name + " was saved.";
                var dialog1 = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(" File " + file.Name + " was saved. ");
                await dialog1.ShowAsync();
            }
            else if (status == FileUpdateStatus.CompleteAndRenamed)
            {
                // TextBlock1.Text = "File " + file.Name + " was renamed and saved.";
                var dialog2 = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(" File " + file.Name + " was renamed and saved. ");
                await dialog2.ShowAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                // TextBlock1.Text = "File " + file.Name + " couldn't be saved.";
                var dialog3 = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("File " + file.Name + " couldn't be saved.");
                await dialog3.ShowAsync();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // TextBlock1.Text = "Operation cancelled.";
            var dialog4 = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Operation cancelled.");
            await dialog4.ShowAsync();
        }


    }   
}
```

Comment: The `path` parameter is not defined in above code . could share it?

Comment: Can you clarify that. This typically saves the input into a local file

Comment: The better way is that share a [mcve] for us.